# Is there an easier way to assign this variable with object destructuring?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-literal

```
const user = new db.User({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        password: req.body.password,
        email: req.body.email,
        dateCreated: req.body.dateCreated
    })
```

I know there's a way to assign values to an object by giving the attributes the same name as their source but I'm not sure how this would work.

Comment: Perhaps new `db.User(req.body)` is all you need? I still would favor manual mapping though

Comment: Do you want all the object properties or just the ones that are named?

Comment: Your attributes *have* the same name as their source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could deconstruct all of these values above to simplify it:

`const { firstName, lastName, password, email, dateCreated } = req.body`

Then all you would need to do is the following:

```
const user = new db.User({
    firstName,
    lastName,
    password,
    email,
    dateCreated,
})
```

Comment: But then how will I refer to that object later (in the db.User() function)?

Comment: I see, thank you! Will mark this as an answered as soon as I stack overflow allows me.

Comment: Cool, did not know this was possible. Javascript never ceases to amaze me

Comment: For some reason people hate javascript what with it always changing, but updates like that are all good for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a good use case for Automapper.  It will map like names and can collapse variables.
http://automapper.org/

Answer (score -1):

You could also do it as a functional one-liner, but even in this case you still have to repeat property names.

```
const user = new db.User(
  (({firstName, lastName, password, email, dateCreated}) =>
   ({firstName, lastName, password, email, dateCreated}))(req.body)
);
```